# Play Framework WebSocket port

Tags: google-app-engine, playframework, websocket, playframework-2.0

Is it possible to set a different port number for WebSockets with Play Framework 2.6? Different from HTTP requests.   For example, use 9000 for HTTP and 8088 for WS connection?

The reason I'm asking this is that I have a Play Application that uses Websockets and I'm trying to deploy it on Google App Engine. I can not get the WebSocket to work and all of the examples that I can find related to GAE and WebSockets the WS is always on a different port.